# React cannot find image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display an image, but despite serving the folder it's contained within it 404s.

JSX file:

```
render: function(){
...
return
<button type="button" id="powerButton" onClick={this.someFun}><img src="images/power.png"></img></button>
```

in server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your app is being served from "*__dirname + '/images*", so the img will be loaded from whatever *__dirname + '/images/images/power.png* is. You should change the express.static path to point to the root of your application (in your case it might be just __dirname, but usually things like index.html go into public folder which would have the images directory inside of it)

Comment: Chrome's console is telling me that it's looking for the path in `http://localhost:2000/images/power.png`. I've tried moving the image into the folder containing index.html and adding `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });` to server.js but no luck